# Git before merge hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am looking for a hook that triggers before every merge in git.
I tried the pre-merge-commit hook with the following code:
`echo "pre-merge commit hook triggered"`

But nothing is triggered or shown in the log file when I merge dev into main for example.

Comment: you might be on a not-new-enough git version?

Comment: There is no hook that is run before the merge even begins, because this is not "hook-worthy". You can achieve this effect by writing your own wrapper around `git merge`. The pre-merge-commit hook is run after the textual merge has been carried out, but before the commit is created.

Comment: What's your Git version? pre-merge hook was added in [2.24](https://github.blog/2019-11-03-highlights-from-git-2-24/).